# Angular2 - how to restrict copy/paste in an input field to a limited charaters?

Tags: angular2-forms, typescript2.0

Iam a newbie to frontend. can anyone help me out on how to restrict the input field to take limited character while copy/pasting? I tried doing this way, it works when you type, but breaks when you copy/paste?

```
    <input type="text" disabled="{{isDisabled}}" placeholder="Search" maxlength="50" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (keyup)="updateTable()" />
```

Comment: I was checking this issue and created plnkr but it was working fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/lz0Eq1?p=preview. Can you create plnkr and share here.

Comment: It some how didn't work in my application. So i have (keyup.enter) instead of (keyup), it works as expected using it.